# vb.net Boolean and Nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net, boolean

Let's define this function :

```
Public Function Test(ByVal value As Boolean)
    Return "blabla" + If(value = Nothing, "", If(value, "1", "0"))
End Function
```

I want it to do the following : 
`Test(True) -> "blabla1"`, `Test(False) -> "blabla0"`, `Test(Nothing) -> "blabla"`.

Problem is that `Test(Nothing)` returns "blabla0".

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a Boolean for 3 values. Consider changing the method

Comment: I don't mean to use it for 3 values, i just get boolean value from a database, i'm just handling the case where pulling failed

Comment: @Arty: To check for a null from a database result, you check if the value (type `Object`, not `Boolean`) is `DBNull`, or use the `DataReader.IsDBNull` method.

Comment: You're thinking of null terms of C# or Java. In that context there are three values - True, False or Null (like a tri-state checkbox). However that's not the way Nothing works in Visual Basic. In VB False is Nothing in the context of a boolean. Similarly String.Empty is Nothing in the context of a string. It's confusing but it's not equivalent to null in C# or Java.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `Boolean` value can never be `null` (`Nothing`), the values that are possible are `True` and `False`. You need a nullable value, a `Boolean?`, for it to be able to be null.

Use the `HasValue` and `Value` properties of the nullable value to check if there is a value, and get the value:

```
Public Function Test(ByVal value As Boolean?)
  Return "blabla" + If(Not value.HasValue, "", If(value.Value, "1", "0"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 9):

`Boolean` is a value type, not a reference type.  Therefore, the value of a `Boolean` variable can never be `Nothing`.  If you compare a `Boolean` to `Nothing`, VB.NET first converts `Nothing` to the default value for a `Boolean`, which is `False`, and then compares it to that.  Therefore, testing to see if a `Boolean` variable `Is Nothing` is effectively the same as testing to see if it equals `False`.  If you need a `Boolean` which can be set to `Nothing`, you need to make it a `Nullable(Of Boolean)`.  There is a shortcut for that, though.  To make any value type nullable, you can just add a question mark after the type, like this:

```
Public Function Test(ByVal value As Boolean?)
    Return "blabla" + If(value.HasValue, If(value.Value, "1", "0"), "")
End Function
```

As you'll notice, even with the variable being nullable, you still don't test whether or not it is null by comparing it to `Nothing`.  It may come as a surprise, but `Nullable(Of T)` is actually a value type as well.  So, rather than testing to see if it's `Nothing`, you should use it's `HasValue` property, as I demonstrated in the example.

Comment: The answer from Guffa is good. I selected this answer because it better explains the default behavior of "Nothing" in this context.

Answer (score 3):

When testing against Nothing, you need to use the Is keyword, but you won't be able to pass your value as a Boolean since it only works on reference types.

```
If( value Is Nothing, "", If( value, "1", "0" ) )
```

It is also worth noting that Nothing defaults to the default value if it is not a reference type.

You can change your signature to expect an Object rather than a Boolean if you want to do this.

Comment: Ty for the answer but i prefer avoiding casts when it's not needed. Upvoted anyway ;)

Comment: After seeing the other solutions - I don't blame you, they're cleaner.